# Why can I execute code after "res.send"?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering what the mechanics behind the behaviour of the following code are:

```
res.send(200, { data: 'test data' });
console.log('still here...');
```

My understanding is that `res.send` doesn't *return* the function, but does *close the connection / end the request*. This could explain why I can still execute code after a `res.send` command (I looked through the express source and it doesn't seem to be an asynchronous function).

Is there something else at play that I may be missing?

Comment: sorry, I misread your post and wasn't sure what the issue was with your code since it is perfectly legit. when you call `send` it just pipes data out the http connection and your code continues. you can just use `return` if you want to terminate the code, or just not write anything else. sorry for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Sure `end` ends the HTTP response, but it doesn't do anything special to your code.

You can continue doing other things even after you've ended a response.

What you *can't* do, however, is do anything useful with `res`.  Since the response is over, you can't write more data to it.

```
res.send(...);
res.write('more stuff'); // throws an error since res is now closed
```

This behavior is unlike other traditional frameworks (PHP, ASP, etc) which allocate a thread to a HTTP request and terminate the thread when the response is over.  If you call an equivalent function like ASP's `Response.End`, the thread terminates and your code stops running.  In node, there is no thread to stop.  `req` and `res` won't fire any more events, but the code in your callbacks is free to continue running (so long as it does not attempt to call methods on `res` that require a valid response to be open).

Comment: Ah ok, so the reason that we can continue code after the request is sent is because there is no thread in node to stop?

So the browser, the response is sent, connection is closed, but that doesn't mean the script has exited. I've leveraged this behaviour before but just wasn't sure about the WHY behind it.

Comment: Any ideas on how to return the function after send?

Comment: i mean stop execution, break the function.

Comment: @OscarVGG: No, there is nothing to stop (short of exiting the process).

Comment: In other words, node.js is unlike php where application context = request context.

Comment: the answer I was looking for was `return callback();`. I think this is called "short-circuiting". Sorry if i could not ask it the right way

Comment: @OscarVGG: That's not really short-circuiting, which has a [well-defined meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  That's just invoking the callback and returning.

Comment: this answer was very helpful and has convinced me to leave nodejs for ideological reasons.

Comment: @jkatzer ideology is weak. pragmatism wins.

Comment: @ i agreed with that,but how can i stop execution of code after res.end

Comment: @PrabjotSingh just always write `return res.send(...);` or `return res.end();`

Comment: That doesn't really guarantee anything -- async callbacks in scope can still run.

Comment: Of course, try to remember that Node is just an execution environment, if you are using expressjs, this is your web server. What you are saying is like wondering why Apache keeps running after php returns a response. You can either choose to use this extra capacity, maybe you want to log the state of the response after it is sent, or do some other application functions, its up to you. However, with great power, comes great responsibility...

Comment: @AnatolyG I read your comment at least 5 times while reading this comment section and I read it plagiarism everytime and was laughing on it, now on myself. Lol.

Answer (score 54):

**Edit:** I no longer do what is explained below, as you shouldn't return a value when there is no need for it. It makes your code less readable and looks hackish. Instead, I suggest separating the return statement from the `res.send()`. @slavafomin explained this well in the comments.

A simple way to stop the execution of the function and send a response at the same time is by doing

```
return res.send('500', 'Error message here');
```

This allows you to use short `if` statements to handle errors such as:

```
if (err) {
    return res.send('500', 'Error message here');
}
```

The exact *return* of the `res.send` function is an *object* that *seems to contain the entire state of the connection after you ended it* (request, status, headers, etc.), but this should be unimportant since you won't be doing anything with it.

Comment: This is a great point, but not technically the answer,. since the question is more about the why than the how. Great contribution nonetheless, hence the upvote :).

Comment: Yea, at the time I couldn't comment however, so I had to post an answer.

Comment: I would recommend against using this technique. It makes code shorter, but  it also makes it less meaningful and vague, cause it uses incorrect semantics. If you are not using the value from the function, then you shouldn't return one. Also it could break typed JavaScript (like TypeScript) and tools using static code analysis. In other words: it looks hackish and unprofessional.

Comment: @SlavaFominII It can be like this: `res.send('500', 'Error message here');return;` inside `if` statement.

Comment: @SlavaFominll I think this method is so common you can't call it hackish anymore. As for static analyzers - since express developers are the ones handling returns from this function, I'm pretty sure there is not much to worry about. Did you encounter a specific problem?

Comment: If you are concerned about returning unused values, you can use the `void` keyword:
`return void res.send('500', 'Error message here');`. This will ensure that `undefined` is returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is with this library: [on-finished](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished)

```
var destroy = require('destroy')
var fs = require('fs')
var http = require('http')
var onFinished = require('on-finished')

http.createServer(function onRequest (req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('package.json')
  stream.pipe(res)
  onFinished(res, () => {
    destroy(stream)
  })
})
```

Works with *Express* too, for example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
 const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, argsArray);
 ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(res);
 onFinished(res, () => {
   ffmpeg.kill();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but the answers provided and the comments helped. Here's my two cents.
The code that comes after res.send() still runs although the connection with the client gets closed.
In my context, I had a function that checked whether a user existed in my MongoDB db and then return the user else return null.

```js
    export const authenticateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   
    const {username, password} = req.body as IUser
    
    const user = await getUser(username) // returns user or null
    
    if(user === null){
        console.log("user is null")
        res.status(404).send("user not found")
    }

    // if user is null the connection get's closed since the above if block runs 
    // but since res.send() doesn't end the function the code below continues to run
    // this causes an error because user is null 

    const passwordMatch = await compare(password, user!.password)

     if(!passwordMatch){
         res.status(400).send("wrong password")
    }
    }
```

adding an else block should solve this

```js
export const authenticateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   
    const {username, password} = req.body as IUser
    
    const user = await getUser(username) // returns user or null
    
    if(user === null){
        console.log("user is null")
        res.status(404).send("user not found")
    }else{
        const passwordMatch = await compare(password, user!.password)

        if(!passwordMatch){
            res.status(400).send("wrong password")
        }
    }
    }
```