# node.js - console.log does not work

Tags: node.js, console.log

I cant see console.log() messages from rest functions.

```
http.listen(port, ip, function(){
console.log('Express server started on port %s', http.address().port);});
```

Within http.listen(), i can see the logs as expected,
but when i call other rest functions, like:

```
app.get('/aaa', function (req, res, next) {
res.send('hello world');
console.log('hello')});
```

it is not writing any logs,
but it does return "hello world".

when i run it locally on my pc i can see the logs,
but when i deploy it the problem starts again.
i also tried to to write logs with the "fs" api, but it still does not work.

any idea why res.send() does work but console.log() does not?

Comment: How do you start your server when you deploy your code ? It gets outputted somewhere, you probably just don't have access to stdout of that process

Comment: put `console.log` before res.send... res.send must be the last statement in your handler functions....

Comment: That isn't true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180502/node-express-why-can-i-execute-code-after-res-send

Comment: The problem has to do with where it is being deployed. But you have told us nothing about that nor have you given a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.listen instead of http.listen fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the console.log(...) before res.send.
I think res.send() is the end destination of request then process escape after this.