# Conditionally send responses in an Express app

Tags: node.js, express, if-statement

I'm curious whether you can write `if` statements in an Express app to conditionally execute your code without providing `else` statements.

```
if(pred) {
  doSomething()
}
return foo;
calcBar(); // doesn't run.
```

Above is the synchronous code that stops execution after the `return` statement.

My Express function looks like this:

```
app.get('/matches', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await someGraphQLCall();
    if(data.length === 0) {
      res.json({ message: "No data." });
    }
    const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(data.foo);
    res.json({ someOtherData });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({err})
  }
}
```

I know because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180502/why-can-i-execute-code-after-res-send/25038317) that code after the first `res.json` might still be executed. Is there a way to stop that? I don't want the second GraphQL call to execute if the first if condition is met. Is that possible without using `else` ?

**Edit:**

As the question I linked above mentioned, using a `return` statement is a bad option because:

> it also makes it less meaningful and vague, cause it uses incorrect semantics. If you are not using the value from the function, then you shouldn't return one.

Comment: That is a bad reason in my opinion. If your REST API returns no data then you might as well throw a 404 to the user and then continue your code. Return statements is such a basic block of programming that is it no vague what it does. And also what would your return be returning? Well it obviously returns the data to the user asking for it, what more precise statement could you use. I would say that wrapping and hiding this away in single if statements is vague and a horrible solution to this. You could use it to check something like ` if (data.hasSomeData) fetchFromGQL `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `return` keyword on the first response to immediately return from the function.

```
app.get('/matches', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await someGraphQLCall();
    if(data.length === 0) {
      return res.json({ message: "No data." });
    }
    const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(data.foo);
    res.json({ someOtherData });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({err})
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

As an alternative, you can split the logic of the data and building up response. This way you can  use return and it's easier to read:

```
app.get('/matches', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const data = await getDataFromGraphQLCall();
        res.json(data);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ err })
    }
});

async function getDataFromGraphQLCall() {
    const data = await someGraphQLCall();
    if (data.length === 0) {
        return { message: "No data." };
    }
    const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(data.foo);
    return { someOtherData };
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oresztresz. I know I can use `else`, but I asked whether there are possibilities without `else`. And I don't want to use the `return` statement (I edited the question with the reason.

Comment: Would you prefer returning in the next statement? `res.json({ message: "No data." }); return;` In my opinion guard clauses are well known and readable. See: https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are wondering if there is a way to achieve that without the `else`, yes it is.
But, It might not be *THE* cleanest way. IMO, using `return` is the best way to stop the execution of the controller.

Anyways, You can split the chunk of code into middlewares and use ternary operator to conditionally send responses.

In your example, separate out `data = await someGraphQLCall();` as follows:

```
const middlewareOne = async function(req, res, next) {
    let data = [];
    let response = { message: "No data." };
    try {
        data = await someGraphQLCall();
        req.locals.data = data; // <- attach the data to req.locals
    } catch (err) {
        response = { err };
    }
    data.length === 0 ? res.json(response) : next();
};
```

And then, mount the `middlewareOne` *BEFORE* your controller:

```
app.get("/matches", middlewareOne, async function controller(req, res) {
    try {
        const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(req.locals.data.foo);
        res.json({ someOtherData });
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ err });
    }
});
```

How this works is, the `controller` function would only be executed by express if the `next()` is called from the previous middleware -- `middlewareOne` in the example.
And as `middlewareOne` only calls `next()` if the `data.length` is not 0, it would work as you expected.

---

For more information on passing data from one middleware to other, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451053/req-locals-vs-res-locals-vs-res-data-vs-req-data-vs-app-locals-in-express-mi)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Admittedly, using `else` is a lot better then.

Comment: Does the `app.get()` have access to data, even though it was declared using `let` in `middlewareOne`? Because there you use it with (and I need to use it with) `data.foo` as input for the next GraphQL call.

Comment: Do you want to access the data from `middlewareOne` into the `controller`?

Comment: In I want to access it in `app.get`.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement terminates the function execution in this context. In my opinion, you should handle the success case then the error case since the code will be read top to bottom.

In `if` statement, data could be `undefined` or `null`.

You can read more here: [MDN - return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

```
app.get('/matches', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await someGraphQLCall();

    // alternative, if (data && data[0]) {
    if (data && data.length) {
      const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(data.foo);
      return res.json({ someOtherData });
    }

    return res.json({ message: "No data." });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // log error with logger and drain to loggly.
    res.json({ err })
  }
}
```

With `Void` operator:

Void operator allows you to return undefined but evaluate the given expression.

You can read more here: [MDN - Void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

```
app.get('/matches', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await someGraphQLCall();

    // alternative, if (data && data[0]) {
    if (data && data.length) {
      const someOtherData = await someOtherGraphQLCall(data.foo);
      return void res.json({ someOtherData });
    }

    return void res.json({ message: "No data." });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // log error with logger and drain to loggly.
    res.json({ err })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you akinjide. I don't want to use the `return` statement (I edited the question with the reason.

Comment: Hi Hester, That's a valid reason, you should look at the void operator