# How can I manage lengthy task functions in Node.js Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I manage lengthy task functions in Node.js Express.js to manage lengthy task functions effectively, and prevent timeout errors? Presently, my application contains a time-consuming function, the response of which I don't require immediately, but I still want it to execute its tasks. How can I ensure that I receive the API response while allowing the function to execute in the background?

IS THERE ANY WAY AROUND TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM? MY MAIN GOAL IS TO AVOID TIMEOUT ERRORS MY MAIN MAKE COUPLE MINS TO COMPLETE THE TASK

Why i tried: (I'm using typescript)

```
import fs from 'fs'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { Worker } from 'node:worker_threads';

api.ts
router.post('/run-long-task', async (req, res) => {
    const taskId = uuidv4();

    const worker = new Worker(file, {
        workerData: { taskId },
        eval: true
    });

    tasksById.set(taskId, {
        status: 'running',
        started: Date.now(),
    });

    worker.on('message', async () => {
        try {
            tasksById.set(taskId, { status: 'completed' });
        } catch (error) {
            tasksById.set(taskId, { status: 'error', error: error.message });
        }
    });

    tasksById.set(taskId, {
        status: "running",
        started: Date.now(),
        worker,
    });

    worker.on("message", (status) => {
        tasksById.set(taskId, { status });
    });

    worker.on("error", (error) => {
        tasksById.set(taskId, { status: "error", error: error.message });
    });

    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            if (tasksById.get(taskId)?.status === "running") {
                tasksById.set(taskId, {
                    status: "error",
                    error: `Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`,
                });
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    res.json({ taskId });
})

worker.ts:
import { parentPort } from "node:worker_threads";

async function performTask() {
    // Long Task Function 
 }

if (parentPort) {
    parentPort.on('message', (task) => {
        performTask()
        parentPort?.postMessage({ success: '1' });
    });
}
```

Comment: if u dont want to return anything from the long task u can do the res.status before performTask

Comment: @cmgchess Im doing this not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180502/why-can-i-execute-code-after-res-send

Comment: @cmgchess Can you give an example what you mean?

Comment: @cmgchess - That would still leave the main thread tied up and unable to respond to other requests.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is true. any invocations on the server would have to wait

Comment: Message broker? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html?

Comment: @kennarddh Can you give a example with this in nodejs?

Comment: the example is in the link. but you need to host the messag broker

Comment: @kennarddh Can you give me one here maybe according to my question? I tried bullmq but it doesn't support serverless hosting providers

Comment: I dont know with serverless.

Comment: Is this a thread-blocking task? does it need to be? Running something in a worker, or as a child process, is an already solved problem. but without knowing the nature of the task you're trying to run... we're just working under assumptions on what is actually needed.

Comment: @KevinB Well the task is to fetch some ML models API which is a very long task

Comment: @James well, that's exactly my point. That's an http request, so you'll spend 99.99% of the time on that request waiting, which means the server can continue doing work. There's likely no need for a worker in this case.

Comment: @Kevin B Then what should i do Kevin?

Comment: Does the fetch prevent other requests from being handled when not using a worker? What problem were you trying to solve by using a worker?

Comment: Well I don't need any response from my main API, I just want to call it and it will fetch some data from those ML model, and again that ML model API will fetch another API, and the work is done.

Comment: @James right, but, that just means you need to res.json() without waiting. it doesn't mean you need a worker....

Comment: @KevinB Yep, You got me, But then what should I do in that case Vercel gives me serverless timeout errors after few seconds 15 seconds

Comment: @James i'd suspect that means your description of what the long running task is is incomplete, or, you're still waiting for it to finish before responding.

Comment: Yes, What should i do?

Comment: I can't possibly tell you how to fix a problem you haven't described.

Comment: I'm confused, How can i  describe you?

Comment: **You need to narrow down your problem.** Vercel timing out isn't a relevant piece of information on it's own. Your question currently is: "I have a long running task and to fix it i used a worker, but the worker isn't working, how can i fix the worker". What you failed to include is what the long running task is, why it needs a worker in the first place, and what exactly is timing out and why. It appears as though you tried to build an entire solution without testing any of the parts along the way to see if/how they work.

Comment: You haven't even shown us how you're calling the long running task without a worker to demonstrate why a worker is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the task takes so long that your browser times out the request while it's running, you don't want to run it on the main thread *at all*, whether before or after you send your response to that API call — because the main thread will be tied up and unable to process any subsequent calls until it's finished.

Instead, run the task in a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html). Worker threads run independently of the main thread. You can use messaging to communicate between the main thread and the worker thread (for instance, so the worker knows what to start doing, and later the main thread knows the task is complete).

If you can't run the task in a worker thread for whatever reason, then the level of complexity goes up markedly. You may need to have a worker process (compute node) running elsewhere and a message queue to pass messages to it. Going into detail on that is beyond the scope of an answer to the question as posted.

FWIW, here's a **very rough** example of using a worker thread, see comments:

```
// Something to keep track of active tasks.
// Just using a Map like this is probably NOT a good idea, at least not without
// code that cleans out old tasks periodically. But my goal here is to give
// you *some* structure you can refine.
const tasksById = new Map();

// An endpoint that starts the task
app.post("/api/start-task", (req, res) => {
    // Get a unique ID for this task
    const taskId = uuid();

    // Run the worker
    const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", {
        workerData: {
            // ...here you could use messaging to send details of what needs to be done to the worker...
        },
    });

    // Remember this task in the map
    tasksById.set(taskId, {
        status: "running",
        started: Date.now(), // You could use this to clear out old entries with a periodic process.
        worker, // You could use this to terminate the worker when removing a task.
    });

    // Accept status updates from the worker
    worker.on("message", (status) => {
        tasksById.set(taskId, { status });
    });

    // Handle errors from the worker
    worker.on("error", (error) => {
        tasksById.set(taskId, { status: "error", error: error.message });
    });

    // If the worker exits with a non-zero exit code and the task
    // is "running", flag it as having failed
    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            if (tasksById.get(taskId)?.status === "running") {
                tasksById.set(taskId, {
                    status: "error",
                    error: `Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`,
                });
            } else {
                // ...probably worth doing *something* to report the error...
            }
        }
    });

    // Reply with the task ID
    res.json({ taskId });
});

// An endpoint the caller can use to get the status of a task.
// NOTE: This requies polling, which is usually a bad idea.
// Ideally, use a web socket or something similar. But doing an
// example of that is really out of scope.
app.get("/task-status/:taskId", (req, res) => {
    // Get the task ID from the request, get the status, report back
    const { taskId } = req.params;
    const task = tasksById.get(taskId);
    const status = task?.status ?? "not found";
    res.json({ taskId, status });
});

// An endpoint the caller can use to explicitly clean up a task it no longer needs.
app.get("/remove-task/:taskId", (req, res) => {
    const { taskId } = req.params;
    const task = tasksById.get(taskId);
    let status;
    if (task) {
        tasksById.delete(taskId);
        task.worker.terminate();
        status = "removed";
    } else {
        status = "not found";
    }
    res.json({ taskId, status });
});
```

Again, that's **very rough**.

That's just one approach, though. Another approach would be to start the worker on startup but have it sit there idle, then use messaging to tell it to process something.

Comment: Can you please give a code example maybe? One problem for me is I'm using a serverless hosting service.

Comment: @James - There are too many different ways to do it/things that would be specific to your code. The linked documentation shows how to create and run a worker thread and how to communicate between the main thread and the worker. (I wouldn't expect a "serverless" host to forbid worker threads, though of course it might.)

Comment: i get this error import express from 'express';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. and i m using typescript and said to use your solution

Comment: @James - There's no reason to have an `import` statement inside your handler function (and it is, as Node.js is telling you, a syntax error). Nothing in the answer above tells you to do that.

Comment: Please check my edited quastion whati tried

Comment: @James - Please roll back that edit, it substantially changes the question. Substantially changing the question after it's received answer(s) is not okay on Stack Overflow. I have, though, put a very rough example of how you might do this in the answer (I decided to see if I could do one quickly when I saw your comment above saying you were trying to `import` inside your handler).

Comment: i get same error import express from 'express'; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Please check my editpost agian

Comment: @James - Sounds like you're not using ESM. I suggest switching to it. But if you want to keep using the outdated CommonJS module format, just use `require` calls instead of `import` statements.

Comment: unfortunately its not working with serverless sad! Vercel

Comment: @James - Frankly, that seems fairly unlikely to me (*possible*, but unlikely). What are you seeing to suggest you can't use `Worker` in Vercel? Can you cite documentation saying that `Worker` is disallowed in Vercel?

Comment: that long task function is not doing it's job I waited a lot but it didn't run.  I found this GitHub issue on Vercel can you please  check https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1993

Comment: Please check my edited question what i try i updated it

Comment: @James - Please read my comments above more carefully. 1. Questions should not be moving targets, please stop editing your attempts at solutions *into* the quesiton. 2. Please answer my questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167599/how-can-i-manage-lengthy-task-functions-in-node-js-express-js#comment136044890_77167638).

Comment: I just found some GitHub issues i linked in my comments, Maybe Vercel does support Woker but i dontknow how to use them

Comment: @James - Sorry, I missed the first of the double comments. Well, you've since received [a reply saying `Worker` works](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1993#issuecomment-1733241353), so it comes down to how you're using it, which is frankly out of scope for the question you asked. If you need help using a worker thread in Vercel, I suggest pursuing it in that github issue, and/or searching for previous questions about that here on SO, and if you don't find any, asking a question about it.

Comment: Any package in your mind that solves this problem

Comment: @James - I can't think of anything in particular I'd recommend. If you really can't use a worker thread, you may need a worker *process*, some kind of compute node, and communicate with it through messaging queues. Good luck with it.

Answer (score -1):

With example of T.J. Crowder and this example try to put your long function inside `worker.ts` `parentPort.on()`.

`index.ts`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync("./worker.ts",{ encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
const { Worker } = require('node:worker_threads');

function runService(worker) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    worker.on('message', resolve);
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
    })
    worker.postMessage({toworker:"run"});
  })
}

async function run() {
  console.log(file)
  const worker = new Worker(file, {
    eval: true
  });
  const result = await runService(worker)
  console.log(result);
}

run().catch(err => console.error(err))
```

`worker.ts`:

```
const { parentPort } = require('node:worker_threads');
parentPort.on('message', (task) => {
  parentPort.postMessage( {success:'1'});
});
```

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by. "above and this example"  I'm trying run performTask in background do you mean on parentPort.on('message' i cal the  performTask

Comment: Please check my edited question what i tried i updated it

Comment: you need to send a message to worker_thread for it to start working.In your code before res.json({ taskId }); add worker.postMessage({toworker:"run"});. change {towrker:"run"} for what you need

Comment: Do you have a minimum code on GitHub that does that, please?  like running a function in background without getting timeout errors on Vercel?